# EF Mapping One To Many

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to figure out how to map the following relationship:

- The "Relation" entity requires a "Node" and a "RelatedNode".
- The Node entity has a collection of "Relations" (HasMany), where the Node is required to be the Relation.Node OR Relation.RelatedNode.

**The current mapping is resulting in a table that looks like this:**

```
[Id],[NodeId],[RelatedNodeId],[RelationType],[Node_Id]
```

*[Node_Id]* is getting automatically created, and this is what I am trying to avoid.

**Relation Entity:**

```
public class Relation
{
    private Relation()
    {

    }

    public Relation(int nodeId, int relatedNodeId)
    {
        NodeId = nodeId;
        RelatedNodeId = relatedNodeId;
    }

    public Relation(Node node, Node relatedNode)
    {
        Node = node;
        RelatedNode = relatedNode;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int NodeId { get; set; }

    public Node Node { get; set; }

    public int RelatedNodeId { get; set; }

    public Node RelatedNode { get; set; }

    public RelationType RelationType { get; set; }
}
```

Fluent-API:

```
// Relation
modelBuilder.Entity<Relation>().Map(m =>
{
    m.ToTable("Relations");
});
modelBuilder.Entity<Relation>()
    .HasKey(t => t.Id)
    .Property(t => t.Id)
    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
modelBuilder.Entity<Relation>().HasRequired(t => t.Node).
    WithMany().HasForeignKey(t => t.NodeId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
modelBuilder.Entity<Relation>().HasRequired(t => t.RelatedNode).
    WithMany().HasForeignKey(t => t.RelatedNodeId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);


// Node
modelBuilder.Entity<Node>().Map(m =>
{
    m.MapInheritedProperties();
    m.ToTable("Nodes");
});
modelBuilder.Entity<Node>().HasMany(t => t.Relations);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Node>().HasMany(t => t.Relations);
```

You've already specified this relationship above.

---

Entity Framework is adding that column to represent a relationship from Relation to Node. Since you specify the HasForeignKey for "Node" and "RelatedNode", it creates the "NodeId" and "RelatedNodeId" columns (as you expect and want).

The "Node_Id" column is what EF would generate when it needs a FK that hasn't been specified. So, somewhere EF is being told that there is a relationship from Node to Relation and the FK is not being specified (EG the line removed)

Comment: I've removed that.  The DB schema created still has the [Node_Id] (not desired), as well as the desired [NodeId] and [RelatedNodeId]).

Comment: Hmmm that should've been the cause. How are you generating the schema? When I use CodeFirst migrations, I always forget to use -force and sometimes my changes aren't reflected.

Comment: I just deleted the database as a whole, and ran it.  I have disabled code-first migrations.

Comment: Hmmm. What does Node inherit from? IE could the MapInheritedProperties be affecting this?

Comment: Node does have a BaseClass that it inherits from!  What is there issue here?

Comment: Sorry, I've added more information to my answer. Hopefully, that should add some context, and allow you to find the problem.

Comment: Thanks.  It makes sense that this is what is happening here, but I am failing to find it anywhere in the mapping.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91519/discussion-between-vlad274-and-blgrnboy).